# inject my site configuration in other module in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have this config for my site :

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

export let APP_CONFIG = new InjectionToken<IAppConfig>('app.config');
export interface IAppConfig {
    apiEndpoint: string;
    headersOptions: HttpHeaders;
}

export const AppConfig: IAppConfig = {
    apiEndpoint: 'https://localhost:44354/',
    headersOptions : new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
};
```

and i need use the `core.module` for using the `config` :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot()
  ],
  exports: [],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_CONFIG,
      useValue: AppConfig,
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: RequestInterceptor, multi: true
    }
  ],
})
export class CoreModule {
  constructor( @Optional() @SkipSelf() core: CoreModule) {
    if (core) {
      throw new Error("CoreModule should be imported ONLY in AppModule.");
    }
  }
}
```

i using the `core.module` in `app.module` .

this my `app.module` :

```
    @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TopHeaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    SharedModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    CoreModule,
    NgZorroAntdModule
  ],
  providers:[{ provide: NZ_I18N, useValue: en_US }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

now i need to use the `AppConfig` in my service :

```
   constructor(httpClient: HttpClient,  @Inject(APP_CONFIG) private appConfig: IAppConfig) {
    super(httpClient);
}
```

but it show me this error :

> Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[[object Object]]:

**whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem???**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your core module like the following (**Remove** `multi: true`)

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot()
  ],
  exports: [],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_CONFIG,
      useValue: AppConfig //multi: true -> Remove here
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: RequestInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
})
export class CoreModule {
  constructor( @Optional() @SkipSelf() core: CoreModule) {
    if (core) {
      throw new Error("CoreModule should be imported ONLY in AppModule.");
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can inject in your service as below:

```
@Injectable()
export class MainService {

  constructor(@Inject(APP_CONFIG) private appConfig: IAppConfig) { }

  getEndPoint(): string {
    alert(this.appConfig.apiEndpoint);
    return this.appConfig.apiEndpoint;
  }
}
```

[**Stackblitz Here**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vh2g5v)